# Java Can I set variable in class depending on the input

Tags: java

I would like following effect -> I have object of class FluidArray which will be an array, but depending on the input it will be either int array or String array: 

FluidArray XXX = new FluidArray; 
XXX.YYY[] might be either String or int 

In this case variable YYY of class XXX might be int array or String

Can I somehow declare variable type depending on some choice?

```
public class FluidArray
{
    VarType YYY;
    public static void FluidArray(int a)
    {
        double[] YYY = new double[15];
    }
    public static void FluidArray(String a)     
    {
        String[] YYY = new String[15];
    }     
}
```

Let's say I want to make a sort method. 
I input there unsorted array. 
I take out sorted array. 
The catch is I might want to sort String, double or int array and I don't want to write 3 sorting methods - I thought that my sorting method might work on some defined object and this object will be either String, double int depending on my choice.


**I am trying to use Generic type, I got so far sth. like this:**

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FluidArray<Integer> arrTest = new FluidArray<>();
        arrTest.arr[1]=2;
        arrTest.arr[2]=3;
        arrTest.arr[3]=4;
    }
    public static class FluidArray<arrType>    
    {
        public arrType[] arr = (arrType[])new Object[15];
    }
}
```

I don't understand, why I can't get access to the array, compiler ends when inserting first value.

Comment: No. What are you trying to do and why? You might want to use generics or use `object` (or `object[]`) as the type of your field. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: No, and it does not make sense to do it. Closest you can get is storing it in a map. Key can be input and value can be whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). Thats what they are supposed to do

Comment: I went through it, added sample code in the question.
I am encountering the error though.